# Convert Spring Data Specification to query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, testing, spring-data-jpa, specifications

Any thought how to convert spring data specification into a simple query?
The goal is to do multiple assertions in the test on the specification. I don't want to use specification on any test db, just want smth like specification.getParams to ensure all fields are set into specification, but there seem to be no such method

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:

Don't

With tests like these you are testing objects from a highly complex API (the Criteria API or JPQL or SQL), which only has a loose relationship with what you are actually interested in because there are many ways create queries, which all will have the same result. It's a little like testing a method by assuring that it contains an `if` on the third row.

Instead go for integration tests using [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/)